# How add .net Framework4 in Installshield 2009

Tags: c#, installshield

I am using Installshield 2009 and I create a setup (install script project)

Now I want to change my setup to .NET 4 in Installshield

How do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to include .NET 4 installer? Or do you want to set the prerequisites?

Answer (score 0):

InstallShield created an [expansion pack for IS2010](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/selfservice/documentLink.do?externalID=Q209084) but you are on 2009.   InstallShield contains a prereq editor that you can use to author your own prereqs.  A tutorial for .NET 3.0 can be found here:

[Using InstallShield 12 to Install .NET Framework 3.0](http://blog.iswix.com/2006/11/using-installshield-12-to-install-net.html)

and

[Tutorial: Adding Setup Prerequisites to InstallShield package](http://shieldmaster.wordpress.com/2009/04/26/tutorial-adding-setup-prerequisites-to-installshield-package/)

I bet you could also download IS2010 eval, apply the expansion pack and then copy the .PRQ files to your IS2009 installation...

Comment: thanks
I am understand
Tools/prereguisite Editor/Files to include/Add multiple File